# Is nlog(n) Big Theta(n)? Master Theorem

Tags: runtime, big-o, master-theorem

Is n⋅log(n) in Θ(n)?
Im asking this because I am solving reccurrences using the master theorem.

The equation is T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n log n

The solution says that it fulfills case 2, meaning T(n) = Θ(n log(n)).

I don't understand how n log(n) could be O(n), shouldn't n log(n) be greater than n when n > 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, n log n ≠ Θ(n). To see this, notice that

> lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> ((n log n) / n) = lim<sub>n → ∞</sub> log n = ∞

Since this limit tends toward infinity, we see that n log n is not Θ(n). Did you find a source that says otherwise?

Hope this helps!

Comment: The source for this is at http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~moreno/CS424/Ressources/master.pdf

Comment: Question number 6, while not directly stating that nlogn = theta(n) implies that it does with the solution.

Comment: In the question you've linked, you fall into the case where f(n) = Theta(n^{log_b a} log^k n) with k = 1. Plugging in those values of a, b, and k, that simplifies to Theta(n log n), so that case is applicable because n log n = Theta(n log n). Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah it does make sense in the context of the master theorem as stated on the page. Its just strange, as my text book (intro to algorithms et al cormen) doesnt include the bit about k

Answer (score 0):

Θ(n⋅log(n)) is not O(n), it's O(n⋅log(n)), which is the correct solution.